# C#, Android: Search every element of a list with a string and return elements sorted by number of matching characters

Tags: c#, android

Oh boy, this is a tough one:

I have my list:

```
    private List<Tasks> tasks;
```

Now, I made an edittext where users can type in a string that is supposed to search every element in within my list "tasks" if the names match the search request. If true, it is supposed to write all those matching elements onto a textview and display them sorted by matching rate.

Say im searching for "ska" in my list with the elements

1. Skooma
2. Skate
3. Style
4. Halfpipe

It is supposed to return in that order:

1. Skate (three character are matching)
2. Skooma ( two are matching )
3. Style ( only the S is matching )

This is how far I have gotten ( not much, yes ...)

```
    private string SearchList(string search)
    {
        string res = null;

        tasks = Libary.Instance.getTasksBasedOnSubCategory(1);

        bool itemExists = tasks.Any(x => x.Name == search);

        return res; 
    }
```

How would you guys go on about this?
Thanks :)

// MY SOLUTION

Thanks to you, this is what I did ( just for completition ...)

```
private void FormatListToString(string search)
        {
            linLayResults.RemoveAllViews();

            for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++) // in jeder sub suchen... könnte dauern und statisch
            {

                tasks = Libary.Instance.getTasksBasedOnSubCategory(x);

                List<string> stringlist = new List<string>();

                foreach (var task in tasks )
                {
                    stringlist.Add(task.Name.ToLower().ToString());
                }

                SortingList(stringlist, search);

            }
        }

        private void SortingList(List<string> list, string keyword)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> filterLst = list.Where
                (s => s.Contains(keyword.ToLower().ToString()));

            var result = filterLst.OrderBy(s => !s.StartsWith(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                 .ThenBy(s => !s.ToLower().Contains(keyword));

            foreach (string s in result)
            {
                FormatTextView(s);
            }

        }

        private void FormatTextView(string s)
        {
            TextView xy = new TextView(this);
            xy.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s);

            xy.SetTypeface(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            xy.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#000000"));
            xy.TextSize = 18;
            xy.SetPadding(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / 50,
                          intHeightOfDisplay / 50, 0, 0);

            xy.Click += delegate
            {

            };

            linLayResults.AddView(xy);
        }
```

Converted all the lists that I needed into a string List, then used the edittext to find it per keyword. removed all uppercases. Then put it all into a textview that reenabled the uppercases on every first letter of every string.

AWESOME!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not a clean but its a working solution.

```
public void SortingList(List<string> list,string keyword)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> filterLst = list.Where(s => s.StartsWith(keyword[0].ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            var result = filterLst.OrderBy(s => !s.StartsWith(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                 .ThenBy(s => !s.ToLower().Contains(keyword));

            foreach (string s in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

        }
```

Comment: thanks that did work BUT: ive noticed that no matter what i send as keyword, the results are only the first letter of what i type in. or am i just wrong?

Comment: Yes, if you want to change to work for phases not only on beginning just change from starts with to contains.
IEnumerable<string> filterLst = list.Where(s => s.Contains(keyword[0].ToString()));

Comment: sorry, i seem to fail to understand. I understood that "keyword[0]" means the first letter of whatever is typed in. if i were to change the 0 to 3 then the fourth letter of my string is what will be searched for. But what I need would be that if I am typing in "SKA" only results that literally state "...ska..." in wihtin their name get listed. So forinstance the word "skateboard" would be listed, but not the word "skooma" since it doesnt say SKA in it only sk. I am sorry for missleading you in my initial question. I make sure to upvote and check as correct answer if u have the time :) thanks!!

Comment: Oh, I think I found it. I just changed "startswith" with "contains". Unfortunately that still is case sensitive. apart from that it works like a charm THANKS!

Comment: Well  in my first comment i forget to remove that [0]. Solution for that is to make them all lower/upper using ToLower() or ToUpper(), keyword.ToUpper()

Answer (score 1):

I would use helper function to evaluate a match between word and search parameter:

```
private static int GetMatchScore(string word, string pattern)
{
    return pattern.TakeWhile((c, i) => i < word.Length && 
                                       Char.ToLower(c) == Char.ToLower(word[i]))
                  .Count();
}
```

GetMatchScore returns the number of matching letters at the beginning of word

the query to find and order matches would look like this:

```
var words = new List<string>{ "Skooma", "Skate", "Style", "Halfpipe" };
string filter = "Ska";  

var search = words.Select(word => new {word, score = GetMatchScore(word, filter)})
                  .Where(m => m.score > 0)
                  .OrderByDescending(m => m.score)
                  .Select(m => m.word);
```